# Remove gridlines from an image for digit recognition in python

Tags: python, image-processing, fft

My image looks like this [image]

I found a similar question here: [How to invert colors of image with PIL (Python-Imaging)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498875)
But I could not understand how to implement it for my image.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ? And what have you tried so far ?

Comment: (1) What Python packages are you using to solve this problem? (2) What exactly do you want to do? Do you want to extract out the digits as separate blobs, or do you simply want to remove the gridlines from the image while leaving the rest of the image intact? Your question is currently too broad to answer as there are multiple interpretations and multiple solutions depending on each interpretation.

Comment: @rayryeng@gwen I am trying to remove the gridlines from the image so that I can cut the image into 10 parts. Its crucial that each part has only one digit and that each part is of equal size. Its for a digit recognition project,

Comment: Why don't you segment out the digits and ignore the grid lines? You also haven't told us which Python packages you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Dilation will erase the thinnest lines, but damage the characters a little.

It is so much easier to ignore the lines at the blob detection stage...

[image]